# Generate Random number in for loop R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to run a for loop 1000 times generating a new set of new numbers which then run through my function cdfx. However, when I run my code I get: **Error: object 'rdm' not found.**

```
 for (i in 1:1000) {
  rdm[i] <- runif(12, 17, 22)
  cdfxr <- cdfx(rdm[i])
  cdfxr[i] <- cdfxr 
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `rdm` exist before the loop? When you try to index into an object with `[i]` it must first exist. Maybe try `rdm <- vector("numeric", 1000)` before your loop so the array actually exists before you index it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are trying to raw more than one number at a time, in that case `rdm` should be a list and you should be indexing with `[[]]`, So try `rdm <- vector("list", 1000)` before the loop and use `rdm[[i]]` rather than `rdm[i]`

Comment: It would be much faster to generate one large list with `runif(12*1000, 17, 22)` and then subset the entire list as needed.

Comment: Use `replicate(1000, whatever_code)`? Or, as Dave suggested `tapply(runif(12*1000, 17, 22), rep(1:1000, each=12), cdfx)`.